# Ternary operator in jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ternary-operator

I want a button to trigger different functions depending on a variable's value, but the ternary operator doesn't seem to work with a jQuery event trigger.

```
var color = "blue";

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#bot').on('click', ((color==="blue") ? vlu : red));

});

function vlu(event){
    alert("Because the sky is blue...");
    color = "red";
}

function red(event){
    alert("Over the blood-red river.");
}
```

Is there a way to do so? Many thanks.

Comment: you need to wrap it in a closure...

Comment: Your exact code works for me in Chrome 45.0.2454.93 on OSX: https://jsfiddle.net/nuwwqju2/

Comment: Ugh, another example of weirdness, thank you Christian Varga, I didn't check it in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it into a closure, something along the lines of

(**Note**, I did not debug your code, just added a closure where needed)

```js
var color = "blue";

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#bot').on('click', function(e) {
      return ((color === "blue") ? vlu(e) : red(e)));
  }

});

function vlu(event) {
  alert("Because the sky is blue...");
  color = "red";
}

function red(event) {
  alert("Over the blood-red river.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you really need to wrap it in a closure? It works for me without it (in Chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/ho6cfb49/

Comment: @ChristianVarga you are correct sir, it does work without a closure (your fiddle proves this) - however, it's a good practice to use closures  for more complex scenarios (i.e. more logic than a ternary operator) - having said that: wrapping it all with parenthesis is kinda like a closure itself (the returning function is the one added in the callaback in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a closure

```
$('#bot').on('click', ( function() { 
    if (color==="blue") vlu();
    else red();
);
```

You could use a ternary operator, but does not make much sense. Seems weird you just do not put the logic in the method to start.